How to configure Laravel 11 for api restul?
I'm developing a project with a RESTful API, but every time I encounter a 'not found' exception or logout using Sanctum in Laravel, the response is a view or a redirect to a login route. How can I configure Laravel for APIs? I need a JSON response instead of a view.
here are my app.config
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option defines the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset "broker" for your application. You may change these values
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => env('AUTH_GUARD', 'web'),
    'passwords' => env('AUTH_PASSWORD_BROKER', 'users'),
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| which utilizes session storage plus the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication guards have a user provider, which defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| system used by the application. Typically, Eloquent is utilized.
|
| Supported: "session"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication guards have a user provider, which defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| system used by the application. Typically, Eloquent is utilized.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| providers to represent the model / table. These providers may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => env('AUTH_MODEL', App\Models\User::class),
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| These configuration options specify the behavior of Laravel's password
| reset functionality, including the table utilized for token storage
| and the user provider that is invoked to actually retrieve users.
|
| The expiry time is the number of minutes that each reset token will be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
| The throttle setting is the number of seconds a user must wait before
| generating more password reset tokens. This prevents the user from
| quickly generating a very large amount of password reset tokens.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => env('AUTH_PASSWORD_RESET_TOKEN_TABLE', 'password_reset_tokens'),
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Password Confirmation Timeout
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
| window expires and users are asked to re-enter their password via the
| confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
|
*/

'password_timeout' => env('AUTH_PASSWORD_TIMEOUT', 10800),

Note: my routes are in Api.php

send the correct accepts header for json

This question is similar to: How do you force a JSON response on every response in Laravel?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


Open app/Exceptions/Handler.php.
Update the render method to force JSON responses when needed:

use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    // Ensure JSON response for all API routes
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Resource not found'], 404);
        }

        if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated'], 401);
        }

        // Customize other exceptions as needed
        return response()->json(['error' => $exception->getMessage()], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}


Pass application/json in your api request's header and also use api middleware in the api routes

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
